# Whether Apparmor has to be enable for mysql database to work properly

Tags: apparmor

We have OS unbuntu 22.04 with mysql 8.0.33 database and Hugepages is not working properly in 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server.
We have set vm.nr_hugepages = 4646 in sysctl.conf file and large_pages=ON, but in grep -i huge /proc/meminfo output HugePages_Rsvd value is showing 0.Hugepages allocated to mysql is not being used by MySQL, but the memeory is allocated.
When we disable apparmor only for mysql and rebooted the server then value is allocated to HugePages_Rsvd.
Is it feasible to keep apparmor in disable state for MySQL Services in /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld?